# In VBA trying to create a dynamic Sumifs Formula with multiple criterias in multiple sheets

Tags: vba, vba7, vba6

In VBA I am trying to create a sumifs formula with multiple criteria across different workbooks, but I am struggling on the syntax.

```
WorkbookRecut.Worksheets("Summary").Activate
Dim CountRows As Long
Dim CountRows2 As Long
CountRows = WorkbookRecut.Worksheets("Summary").Range("I" & WorkbookRecut.Worksheets("Summary").Rows.Count - 1).End(xlUp).Row
CountRows2 = CashBreaksMetricsWorkbookFinal.Worksheets("CSCIG_Cash Breaks Metrics").Range("I" & CashBreaksMetricsWorkbookFinal.Worksheets("CSCIG_Cash Breaks Metrics").Rows.Count - 1).End(xlUp).Row

CashBreaksMetricsWorkbookFinal.Worksheets("CSCIG_Cash Breaks Metrics").Activate
Range("O6").Formula = _
"=Sumifs(" & [WorkbookRecut].Sheets("Summary").Range("I9").Address & ":" & [WorkbookRecut].Sheets("Summary").Range("I" & CountRows).Address _
& "," & [WorkbookRecut].Sheets("Summary").Range("A9").Address & ":" & [WorkbookRecut].Sheets("Summary").Range("A" & CountRows).Address _
& "," & [CashBreaksMetricsWorkbookFinal].Worksheets("CSCIG_Cash Breaks Metrics").Range("K6").Address(Rowabsolute:=False) _
& "," & [WorkbookRecut].Sheets("Summary").Range("D9").Address & ":" & [WorkbookRecut].Sheets("Summary").Range("D" & CountRows).Address _
& "," & [CashBreaksMetricsWorkbookFinal].Worksheets("CSCIG_Cash Breaks Metrics").Range("N6").Address(Rowabsolute:=False) & ")"
CashBreaksMetricsWorkbookFinal.Worksheets("CSCIG_Cash Breaks Metrics").Range("O6:O" & CountRows2).FillDown
```

### Update

I have updated the most recent code. The only pending issue is the workbooks aren't changing, but all else works as I want :)

Comment: The expected output would be useful here....  I'd start by defining some sheet variables eg `Dim wsSumm As Worksheet: Set wsSumm = WorkbookRecut.Sheets("Summary")`.  That will reduce your code bulk and make it easier to work with.

Comment: Im trying to achieve the formula whereas Test File 4.xlsx is my variable WorkbookRecut =SUMIFS('[Test File 4.xlsx]Summary'!$I$9:$I$307,'[Test File 4.xlsx]Summary'!$A$9:$A$307,$K6,'[Test File 4.xlsx]Summary'!$D$9:$D$307,$N6)

Comment: You've got the formula going into `Range("O9")` but FillDown targetting `Range("I9")`. Is this intended and correct?

Comment: Thanks - dumb mistake on my part. I was less concerned about that part, but definitely saved me time for my next mistake lol,. I updated the code in the main section

Comment: Are you saying I need to add address after each range? It still doesnt cure the issue :( The default .address is already xlreference style, which is what I am using

Answer (score 1):

When creating a formula string to add to a cell you need to take into account where the different ranges are relative to the sheet where you're going to place the formula.  Just calling `Address()` on one of the inputs may not give you what you want.

You can try something like the code below to abstract that part into a separate function:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim wsSumm As Worksheet, wsCBM As Worksheet
    Dim lr As Long, f
    
    Set wsSumm = WorkbookRecut.Worksheets("Summary")
    Set wsCBM = CashBreaksMetricsWorkbookFinal.Worksheets("CSCIG_Cash Breaks Metrics")
    
    lr = wsSumm.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row

    f = "=SUMIFS(" & RealAddress(wsCBM, wsSumm.Range("I9:I" & lr)) & "," & _
                     RealAddress(wsCBM, wsSumm.Range("A9:A" & lr)) & ",$K6," & _
                     RealAddress(wsCBM, wsSumm.Range("D9:D" & lr)) & ",$N6)"
    
    With wsCBM.Range("O9")
        .Formula = f
    End With
    
End Sub

'get a range address for `rngRef`,
'   suitable for use in a formula on worksheet `ws`
Function RealAddress(ws, rngRef As Range) As String
    Dim s As String
    If ws.Parent Is rngRef.Worksheet.Parent Then 'same workbooks?
        If Not ws Is rngRef.Worksheet Then s = "'" & rngRef.Worksheet.Name & "'!" 'diff. worksheets?
        s = s & rngRef.Address(True, True)
    Else
        s = rngRef.Address(True, True, external:=True) 'different workbooks
    End If
    RealAddress = s
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Tim - Appreciate your help, but 'm 99% there with my updated code. Only issue pending is that I cant reference the other workbooks. Its all happening in the CashMetricsWorkbookFinal

Answer (score 0):

For the formula: You're probably looking for the .Address property from each of your Ranges. Something like `Range1.Address & ":" & Range2.Address` To get an output like `$I$9:$I$307`.

But for your Ranges, you need to put the `CountRows` inside the Range input like `WorkbookRecut.Sheets("Summary").Range("A" & CountRows)` and then add the `.Address` to it.

I also agree with @TimWilliams that your formula code could benefit greatly in terms of readability by adding some nicknames for your worksheets.

Here is what your code would look like with those 3 things corrected:

```vb
Public CashBreaksMetricsWorkbookFinal As Workbook
Public WorkbookRecut As Workbook

Dim SumSh As Worksheet
Set SumSh = WorkbookRecut.Sheets("Summary")

Dim CountRows As Long
CountRows = SumSh.Range("I" & SumSh.Rows.Count - 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim CSCIG As Worksheet
Set CSCIG = CashBreaksMetricsWorkbookFinal.Worksheets("CSCIG_Cash Breaks Metrics")

CSCIG.Activate
Range("O9").Formula = _
       "=Sumifs(" & SumSh.Range("I9") & ":" & SumSh.Range("I" & CountRows).Address _
       & "," & SumSh.Range("A9").Address & ":" & SumSh.Range("A" & CountRows).Address _
       & "," & CSCIG.Range("K6").Address _
       & "," & SumSh.Range("D9").Address & ":" & SumSh.Range("D" & CountRows).Address _
       & "," & CSCIG.Range("N6").Address & ")"
       
CSCIG.Range("O9").FillDown
```

Comment: I wrote a little hastily and messily and have made several small edits. Please try again with my latest updated code if an earlier edit didn't work.

Comment: Thanks @toddleson - I think we also need a .address after the first part of the sum range criteria. Also, the code is not switching between workbooks oddly..

Answer (score 0):

We were missing .Address(External:=True)

Thanks all for helping me get there (Finally!)

Final Code Below

```vb
Public CashBreaksMetricsWorkbookFinal As Workbook
Public WorkbookRecut As Workbook

Dim CountRows As Long
Dim CountRows2 As Long

CountRows = WorkbookRecut.Worksheets("Summary").Range("I" & WorkbookRecut.Worksheets("Summary").Rows.Count - 1).End(xlUp).Row
CountRows2 = CashBreaksMetricsWorkbookFinal.Worksheets("CSCIG_Cash Breaks Metrics").Range("I" & CashBreaksMetricsWorkbookFinal.Worksheets("CSCIG_Cash Breaks Metrics").Rows.Count - 1).End(xlUp).Row

CashBreaksMetricsWorkbookFinal.Worksheets("CSCIG_Cash Breaks Metrics").Activate
Range("O6").Formula = _
"=Sumifs(" & [WorkbookRecut].Sheets("Summary").Range("I9").Address(External:=True) & ":" & [WorkbookRecut].Sheets("Summary").Range("I" & CountRows).Address(External:=True) _
& "," & [WorkbookRecut].Sheets("Summary").Range("A9").Address(External:=True) & ":" & [WorkbookRecut].Sheets("Summary").Range("A" & CountRows).Address(External:=True) _
& "," & [CashBreaksMetricsWorkbookFinal].Worksheets("CSCIG_Cash Breaks Metrics").Range("K6").Address(Rowabsolute:=False) _
& "," & [WorkbookRecut].Sheets("Summary").Range("D9").Address(External:=True) & ":" & [WorkbookRecut].Sheets("Summary").Range("D" & CountRows).Address(External:=True) _
& "," & [CashBreaksMetricsWorkbookFinal].Worksheets("CSCIG_Cash Breaks Metrics").Range("N6").Address(Rowabsolute:=False) & ")"
CashBreaksMetricsWorkbookFinal.Worksheets("CSCIG_Cash Breaks Metrics").Range("O6:O" & CountRows2).FillDown
```

Comment: `[WorkbookRecut].Sheets("Summary").Range("I9").Address(External:=True) & ":" & [WorkbookRecut].Sheets("Summary").Range("I" & CountRows).Address(External:=True)` would be better as `WorkbookRecut.Sheets("Summary").Range("I9:I" & CountRows).Address(External:=True)` You only need one range, and the `[]` are redundant.

Comment: Thanks Tim for the additional comments :)

Answer (score 0):

In the formula, you have to double-quote existing quotes:

Change

```
Sheets("Summary")
```

to:

```
Sheets(""Summary"")
```